# @types/google.maps: Cannot find name 'google'

Tags: angular, typescript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Application just needs zip code input from customers to calculate distances between two points in order to recommend the closest store. No need to display/draw a map. Have a valid Google API Key tested with Postman and a regular Chrome at `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?`. But got CORS using `http.get<any>(urlwithparams)` from inside application. Found out Google intentionally not allow request from script, have to use its library.

No problem! After reading many posts and Google's Developer Guide, believe I should use `DistanceMatrixService` and this is the easy sample to follow https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/distance-matrix#maps_distance_matrix-typescript

My component .HTML:

```
<script
      src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=KeyValue&callback=clickFind&v=weekly"
      defer
    ></script>
```

My component .ts:

```
clickFind()
{
    const map = new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService; <<-- Error: TS2663: Cannot find name 'google'
    ....
}
```

Result is `Cannot find name 'google'`. **I have tried all the followings**,

[Cannot find name 'google' angular 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63604420/cannot-find-name-google-angular-8)

[Google Maps API: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44336773/google-maps-api-no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-reque)

[Typescript Error Cannot find name 'google' in ionic2 when using googlemaps javascript API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42173662/typescript-error-cannot-find-name-google-in-ionic2-when-using-googlemaps-javas)

[@types/googlemaps/index.d.ts' is not a module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51084724/types-googlemaps-index-d-ts-is-not-a-module)

https://www.freakyjolly.com/angular-google-maps-using-agm-core/#more-2316

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distance-matrix/distance-matrix#request-examples

https://www.joshmorony.com/getting-started-with-google-maps-in-ionic-2/

eventually came back to the same

> Error: TS2663: Cannot find name 'google'

Summary

1. `@types/googlemaps` has been deprecated, if you install it will be told switching over to `@types/google.maps` even though it still placed `@types/googlemaps` in package.json, so I ran `npm i @types/google.maps --save-dev` instead.
2. The installed version is `"@types/google.maps": "^3.51.0"`
3. Many posts above are using early Angular versions up to 9, or `axios` while mine is Angular v14
4. `@agm/core` should not be needed.
5. Some solutions above build ok but fail at run time for the error.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68353032/error-referenceerror-google-is-not-defined-angular-map

Comment: @MrUpsidown It is solved, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There could me more than one solution, but here is:

1. `npm i -D @types/google.maps`
2. `npm i @googlemaps/js-api-loader`
3. no update to *tsconfig.app.json*, *HTML*
4. TS implementation

   const loader = new Loader({apiKey: 'keyvalue'}).load().then( this.test1);
   test1():void
   {
   var gmd = new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService();
   gmd.getDistanceMatrix
   ({
   origins: ["jacksonville, fl"], destinations: ["chicago, il", "seattle, wa"], travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
   })
   .then(
   (resp) =>
   {
   ... // do whatever
   }
   );
   }

Based on [ERROR ReferenceError: google is not defined Angular Map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68353032/error-referenceerror-google-is-not-defined-angular-map). Thanks to @MrUpsidedown